# Laravel Redirect /login route

Tags: laravel, redirect, model-view-controller, laravel-5, routes

How do I redirect the user if they visit `www.myapp.com/login` or `www.myapp.com/register` to a different domain/route? (Change the route of the login/register).

In Laravel 5.2 which controller actually loads the views for `login` & `register`?

Comment: is there any condition like checking Authentication status or you just want to redirect anyone?

Comment: looks like it is `namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth` and the traits `RegistersUsers` and `AuthenticatesUsers` is where the logic is on redirects for auth

Comment: @jonju redirect anyone.

Comment: Are you looking to redirect the user after login / registration? or are you looking to change the route for login / registration?

Comment: @Chris I am looking to change the route to login / registration to a totally different domain.

Comment: @ArturGrigio So for example: `www.myapp.com/login` to `www.myapp.com/sign-in`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a middleware

**MIDDLEWARE**

```
class redirector{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return redirect('/redirecturl');
        //return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Register you middleware in `App\Http\Kernel.php`

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'redirect' => \App\Http\Middleware\redirect::class,
]
```

Now include the middleware in your route routes.php like below

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'redirect'], function () {
    Route::get('/login',function(){
        return view('login');
    });
    Route::get('/register',function(){
        return view('register');
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect any user, it is faster to do it without touching the application, i.e. if you're using apache, add to your vhost config file:

```
RedirectPermanent /login http://newdomain.com
RedirectPermanent /register http://newdomain.com
```

You can also add it to the `.htaccess` file inside the public folder, but vhost file will be faster.